# How to send SNS message to many FCM tokens without creating Endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, firebase-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

I'm trying to figure out how can I send a message to many FCM clients, from Lambda, using SNS service.
All resources I found are referring to creating an SNS Application Endpoint for desired device token, but I don't understand this approach. If I have thousands of devices, and their tokens can change (I have a mechanism of announcing new tokens and saving them into DynamoDB already developed), should I update them in the SNS endpoints "database" as well, all the time?  
The only example I found is to do it like this:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS()

...

const params = {
    PlatformApplicationArn: '<Platform Arn>',
    Token: '<FCM Token>'
};
    
const endpointData = await sns.createPlatformEndpoint(params).promise();

const paramsMessage = {
    Message: snsPayload,
    TargetArn: endpointData.EndpointArn
};

await sns.publish(paramsMessage).promise();
```

And after that, how can I publish a message for more FCM tokens at once?
I know that I can call Firebase API directly and not to use SNS at all, but I'm curious if it is not intended to use for this scenario, or Am I missing something?